# Checking the significance of the difference between two groups of different length

Tags: r, data-analysis, difference, variable-length, significance

I need to check if the difference between land surface temperature in the past and present within the LULC is statistically significant. LULC units changed over time and the length of the temperature data changed as well because the class grew.

I made data two frames for one of the classes for both periods. LST values from the past have 104 records, from the past - 108.

```
t.test(compact_midrise_1990$LST1990 ~ compact_midrise_2010$LST2010)
```

Ends up with:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = compact_midrise_1990$LST1990 ~  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'compact_midrise_2010$LST2010')
```

The question is how can I check the significance of the differences within the two groups of different lengths in this case.

Data looks like this:

DF1

```
 LCZ1990 LST1990
1       2  14.235
2       2  14.910
3       2  20.534
4       2  15.060
5       2  13.868
6       2  21.732
```

DF2

```
LCZ2010    LST2010
1       2  23.045
2       2  24.038
3       2  23.008
4       2  23.680
5       2  23.645
6       2  25.403
```

Comment: You may have meant to use: 
`t.test(compact_midrise_1990$LST1990 , compact_midrise_2010$LST2010)` 
(comma instead of `~`).  In R `t.test` has two different interfaces, the formula interface (with `~`) would be used to specify an `outcome ~ predictor` type relationship between columns.

Comment: Thank you so so much! I can't believe I spent this amount of time over this for a comma...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have meant to use:

```
t.test(compact_midrise_1990$LST1990 , compact_midrise_2010$LST2010)
```

(comma instead of ~).

In R `t.test` has two different interfaces.  The default interface,

```
t.test(A,B)
```

tests the hypothesis that the mean of the vector `A` equals the mean of the vector `B`.

the formula interface (with `~`) would be used to specify an `outcome ~ predictor` type relationship between columns.

So if you had bound your data frame into a single frame:

```
   YEAR LCZ    LST
1  1990   2 14.235
2  1990   2 14.910
3  1990   2 20.534
4  1990   2 15.060
5  1990   2 13.868
6  1990   2 21.732
7  2010   2 23.045
8  2010   2 24.038
9  2010   2 23.008
10 2010   2 23.680
11 2010   2 23.645
12 2010   2 25.403
```

then you could use:

```
t.test(LST ~ YEAR, data=DF)
```